# Maximum sub-contiguous sum in a circle

Tags: arrays, algorithm

The problem is that I have an array filled with n numbers. I have to determine the maximum sum, but, if the number in the position i is added to the sum, then the numbers i-1 and i+1 can't be added.

The n number are considered to be in a cicle.

For example, if a have the next array:

{6, 9, 1, 2, 8, 6, 3, 7, 12, 5, 65, 66, 2}
The maximun sum would be 99:
9 + 8 + 3 +12+ 65 + 2 = 99

Comment: Please show some effort in solving your homework/interview question first before asking for solution.

Comment: It's not a homework. And, actually, I tried to solve this but I could'nt. I first solved the maximun contiguous sum in a circle. But, I can't figure this one out.

Comment: @RamonVargas: I think you need to say "this is what I tried ..., but it doesn't work because blah blah...". You need to describe what you tried and may be why that didn't work... (you can update the post with these details)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you know that the first element of the array is included. Then you can solve this by dynamic programming: for i = 3 to N - 1, work out the best solution for the first i members of the array by considering the choice of including or not including element i and looking at the score previously calculated for the best solution for the first i-1 or i-2 elements to work out the best you can do for i elements. You don't need to work out the best for N elements because you can't include the last element because you included the first, and the score for the first two elements is the same as the score for the first element because you included it.

The other possibility is that the first element is not included. But you can work out the best score for this in the same way, except considering possibilities for i = 2 to N.

Now you have the answer for the two possible cases - either the first element is included or it is not - so pick the best.

PS - if this isn't homework is there actually a useful application of this? what is it?

Comment: The best way to park cars of varying levels of importance that are slightly too wide for the painted parking lines in a radial carpark?  Yeah, it's a bit of a stretch...

Answer (score 0):

I thought your problem was interesting but didn't want to respond because you haven't showed any effort of your own.

Anyway, since mcdowella has answered the question, I'll try to elaborate his answer a bit more.

Let's take the input array:

```
a = [6, 9, 1, 2, 8, 6, 3, 7, 12, 5, 65, 66, 2]
```

The idea is to step through this array incrementally calculating **two best** solutions. At step `i`, the two solutions are the **best solution including `a[i]`** and the **best solution not including `a[i]`**. Here's an example run of this algorithm with the above array as input:

```
// step = 1
solutions = [6], []
```

This step (step - 1) is obvious, we only have the first element in the array. Note that the first solution component (`[6]`) corresponds to the one including `a[1]` and the second component (`[]`) is the one not including `a[1]`.

```
// step = 2
solutions = [9], [6]
```

In the second step we add `a[2] = 9` into the previous solution which did not include `a[1]`(i.e the second component - `[]`). Then we select the **best of the previous two solutions** as the second component. From here onward we repeat the same process:

```
// step = 3
solutions = [6, 1], [9]

// step = 4
solutions = [9, 2], [9]

// step = 5
solutions = [9, 8], [9, 2]

// step = 6
...
```

You also need to keep track of which solution (if any) contains `a[1]`, because at the final step we shouldn't add `a[n]` to a solution which already contains `a[1]`. This information (can be a boolean flag) can be associated with each of the  two solution components and updated with each step as we go along.